# How to use TypeScript constructor to declare variables

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, typescript

I'm trying to use `TypeScript` constructor in an Angular2 project, and I got confused regarding how to use `class` constructor to initialize the variables:

```
function Auto () {
    this.move = function () {
        console.log('move');
    }
    this.stop = function () {
        console.log('stop');
    }
}
```

Now I will use it in the class:

```
class Car {
    constructor(private _auto: Auto) {
    }

    onMove() {
        this._auto.move();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get this error `Cannot find name Auto`, so could anyone help me understanding what's going on?

And, why `private _auto: Auto` make `_auto` a new instance of `Auto` class?

**Update:** I know that I can use `class` to solve the problem, but I want to understand why `javascript` functions throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because creating a function does not create a type for the compiler to use, so `Auto` does not exist as a type. Right now it's only known as the name of a function.

The easiest way to solve this is to use a class for `Auto` instead:

```
class Auto {
    move() {
        console.log('move');
    }

    stop() {
        console.log('stop');
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
let auto = new Auto();
let car = new Car(auto);
```

---

Alternatively, you could manually describe the type of the function. Here's one example, but don't do this because you should just convert it to a class:

```
interface AutoConstructor {
    new(): Auto;
}

interface Auto {
    move(): void;
    stop(): void;
}

let Auto: AutoConstructor = function() {
    let self = this as Auto;
    self.move = function () {
        console.log('move');
    }
    self.stop = function () {
        console.log('stop');
    }
} as any;

let auto = new Auto();
let car = new Car(auto); // ok
```

Comment: I know that, but I want to understand why using `JS` function throw this error!!